# Add multiple columns with rep in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rep

I'm trying to create a fixed number of columns (in this case 4 columns) with the rep function. In column B is mentioned how often the number 1 should be repeated in those columns. The remaining columns should be filled with 0.

But I get the error message

> "Error in rep(1, B) : invalid 'times' argument"

and don´t know how to fix it

```
test <- data.table(A = c("XYZ", "ZYX", "WER"),
                   B = c(1, 3, 2))
cols <- LETTERS[3:6] 
test[, (cols) := c(rep(1, B), rep(0, length(cols) - B))]  

#result should be 
result <- data.table(A = c("XYZ", "ZYX", "WER"),
                     B = c(1, 3, 2),
                     C = c(1, 1, 1),
                     D = c(0, 1, 1),
                     E = c(0, 1, 0),
                     F = c(0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Sorry, column B was wrong. I have edited the post to clarify also the meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses a bit of non-'data.table' logic, but should be pretty quick still:

```
test[, (cols) := {
  D <- diag(length(cols))
  D[lower.tri(D)] <- 1
  data.table(D[B,])
}]

#     A B C D E F
#1: XYZ 1 1 0 0 0
#2: ZYX 3 1 1 1 0
#3: WER 2 1 1 0 0
```

It works because it creates a matrix with a filled diagonal and lower-triangle, and then uses `test$B` to subset the rows of this matrix.

Alternatively, you could loop over a sequence of the length of the columns to assign, and check if the value is equal or less:

```
test[, (cols) := lapply(1:length(cols), function(x) as.numeric(x <= B))]
```

Some comparative timings adding 24 columns and 3M rows:

```
cols <- LETTERS[-(1:2)]
test <- test[rep(1:3,1e6),]

system.time(test[, (cols) := {
  D <- diag(length(cols))
  D[lower.tri(D)] <- 1
  data.table(D[B,])
}])

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.937   0.651   1.591
```

Beaten by my second effort:

```
system.time(
  test[, (cols) := lapply(1:length(cols), function(x) as.numeric(x <= B))]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.313   0.132   0.446
```

Comment: Very detailed! Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice. Fwiw, if for some reason one wants to go full data.table: `system.time(test[, (cols) := 0L][, test[B == .BY$B, (cols)[seq_along(cols) <= B] := 1L][, NULL], by=B][])` ... maybe more natural to go to long form somehow.